# Regex - Can I shorten this expression?

Tags: java, regex

I need to shorten the expression `\D*(\d+)( days? | hours? | minutes? | seconds? )(ago|from now).*`
It matches a format, which represents time, i.E.: "3 hours ago", "5 days from now", "1 minute ago". It's searching these terms line by line in html-Code.

The programming language I need this in is Java, so I have to match an entire string with the reg. expression.

Comment: Well for starters you don't need `\D*` and `.*` if you're just going to not use the match anyway?

Comment: It doesn't work without `\D*` & `.*`, because I use Java (forgot to mention), in which the matches() method of class String only returns true, if the String follows the exact pattern of the regular expression and because the line in the html-Code has more code before and after the time, it needs to check everything in the line.

Comment: You may use `Matcher.find()` to for partial matches in Java.

Comment: You may move spaces out of the 2nd group :))   `(\d+) (days?|hours?|minutes?|seconds?) (ago|from now)`

Comment: Why would you need to shorten the regex if it works?

Comment: You can also move the `s` at the end of "days" etc. outside the parentheses. Don't see the need either.

Comment: I don't know exactly, IF I need to shorten this expression, I'm just currently trying to find the reason for an exception in my Java code, which could come from an expression, which is too long, but I guess, thats not the reason since the error keeps occuring, even after shortening the expression a bit. I also think, I shouldn't post the code here, because that would be another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get this regex significantly shorter — most of its length is literal text. This is *probably* the shortest which you can get:

```
(\d+) (day|hour|minute|second)(s?) (ago|from now)
```

Though extracting `s?` and making an additional group out of it reduces readability — IMO. (And you *do need* a group around `s?` *if* you want to be able to distinguish between `minute` and `minutes`).

Personally, I find your original regex ok and wouldn't care about [microoptimizations](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/). I would only move spaces out of the group, i.e.:

```
(\d+) (days?|hours?|minutes?|seconds?) (ago|from now)
```

Regarding `String.matches()` — you may use `Matcher.find()` method to match partially.